# tensorflow SKCompat is not compatible with cross_val_score

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a tensorflow classifier with some tools from scikit learn, namely `model_selection.cross_val_score`. When I run the following code (adapted from [this example from the tensorflow docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.1.0/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py)), I get a `TypeError` (see full traceback below).

From what I can tell the problem is that `cross_val_score` tries to clone the estimator by performing what amounts to `estimator.__class__(**estimator.get_params(deep=True))`. For some reason, `SKCompat.get_params` returns `{}`, the init method on the class requires one argument (as shown in the example code) so the operation blows up.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug with tensorflow?

### Failing example

```
"""Example of DNNClassifier for Iris plant dataset."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection

import tensorflow as tf


def main(unused_argv):
  # Load dataset.
  iris = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset('iris')

  # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
  feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(
      iris.data)
  classifier = tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat(
    tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
      feature_columns=feature_columns,
      hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
      n_classes=3
    )
  )

  # Fit and predict.
  scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(classifier, iris.data, iris.target,
          scoring='accuracy')
  print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(scores.mean()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iris.py", line 49, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "iris.py", line 44, in main
    scoring='accuracy')
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 140, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv_iter)
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 603, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.items = list(iterator_slice)
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 140, in <genexpr>
    for train, test in cv_iter)
  File "/Users/Matt/.virtualenvs/numerai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 70, in clone
    new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

### Versions

python: 2.7.3

tensorflow: 1.1.0

scikit-learn: 0.18.1

Comment: This error is because cross_val_score will clone the estimator before each fitting and for that get_params() of SKCompat should return correct parameters [as specified in documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/SKCompat). But for some reason, its returning empty parameters and hence the error.

Comment: @VivekKumar I think you're correct. My follow up question is: am I using the class incorrectly or is this a bug I should file with tensorflow?

Comment: I tried but could not find the example of usage of SKCompat with scikit-learn anywhere. So cannot comment on it. I think you should put an issue on their github page. If not a bug, you will get the proper usage of it.